# Hornetq Core Bridge - one publisher, multiple consumers

Tags: hornetq

Server A publishes data to the topic `source/topic` and two durable subscribers `sub-b` and `sub-c` are configured to listen to the topic. Subscribers  `sub-b` and `sub-c` will receive the identical data.

Is there a way to configure in HornetQ using multiple core bridges to publish message from `sub-b` channel to server B and from `sub-c` channel to server C.

As per the [Horentq documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hornetq/2.2.5.Final/user-manual/en/html/core-bridges.html) they suggest to use core bridge instead of JMS bridge if possible.

> It's always preferable to use a core bridge if you can.

`bridgeType` Schema definition does not seem to support to use subscriber name as in the case of JMS bridge bean definition.

The workaround I came up with is to use JMS but I was wondering if anyone came across this issue before and would you mind sharing your thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0):

A JMS topic (i.e. `source/topic`) is represented in the broker simply as an address.  A JMS subscription (i.e. `sub-b` and `sub-c`) is represented in the broker as a queue associated with the relevant address (`source/topic` in this case).  The queues internal name is a combination of details from the JMS subscriber (e.g. client ID, subscription name, etc.).  When a message is sent to the JMS topic the broker routes a reference to that message to each subscription so that every subscription gets every message (assuming their selectors match).

A core bridge listens for messages arriving in an queue and then forwards those messages to an address either locally or on a remote broker.

In your case, you can create a bridge which listens on the queue of the JMS subscription and then forwards that message to a remote broker of your choosing.